# SQL Select table name

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

A database had has 4 tables that has the same columns EG. SalesJAn, SalesFeb, SalesMarch, SalesApril.

I want to run a query in SQL server or in report builder Where i can change the table name  based on a selection which one of 4 tables will be queried . Eg Filter in report builder

Like this

declare @tablename varchar(50)
set @tablename = 'test'
select * from @tablename

Comment: Are you looking for an alias? As example "SELECT renamedtable.salesJAN AS Sales1 FROM eg AS renamedtable -> would like rename both the column name and the table name for your result. Or do you really want to rename the table within the DB and not within query only?

Comment: Do you mean, based on a selection which one of 4 tables will be queried?

Comment: YES based on a selection which one of 4 tables will be queried. That what I'm looking for

Comment: So what exactly is unclear to you? Of course, this is possible. I think you should edit your question and tell us what you really would like to know.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I don't think that's actually possible in ReportBuilder, or at least it does not seem obvious.

Comment: When i execute that query . I get the following error  " Must declare the table variable "@tablename"."

Comment: What exactly does "based on a selection" mean? Is this a parameter for your report that comes from the user? A column in some other table? A variable? Have you considered normalizing your schema - which is the root cause of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure which will do a select for a given table name. This procedure could look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXECUTE_SELECT
@tbl sysname
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SQL =  N' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl)
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL 
END
```

Then you can execute this procedure for every table name you want. Please see here an example according to your description: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9cfad198a0763d3cd11195cb66adb2ee)

If this doesn't help you, please point out which exactly you still need to know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you that's what i wanted . I appreciate It

Comment: Thank you, then please mark it as correct answer.